# send message to activemq in mvc spring give null pointer exception

Tags: spring-mvc, activemq-classic

I am try to execute sample send and recive message to/from activemq by mvc spring But when I Run the project I get this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.sarf.jms.MessageProducerBean.sendMessage(MessageProducerBean.java:24)
    com.sarf.testactimq.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:42)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My source code  :

MessageObject.java :

```
package com.sarf.data; 

public class MessageObject {
  private String mailId;
  private String message;

 public MessageObject(){}; 
 public MessageObject(String mailId, String message) {
  super();
  this.mailId = mailId;
  this.message = message;
 }
 public String getMailId() {
  return mailId;
 }
 public void setMailId(String mailId) {
  this.mailId = mailId;
 }
 public String getMessage() {
  return message;
 }
 public void setMessage(String message) {
  this.message = message;
 }
}
```

MessageConsumerBean.java :

```
package com.sarf.jms;

import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MapMessage;

import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils;
import com.sarf.data.MessageObject;

public class MessageConsumerBean{

     private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
     private Destination destination;

     public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
         this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
     }
     public void setDestination(Destination destination) {
         this.destination = destination;
     }

     public MessageObject receiveMessage() {
      MapMessage message = (MapMessage) jmsTemplate.receive(destination);
      try {
           MessageObject messageObj = new MessageObject();
           messageObj.setMailId(message.getString("mailId"));
           messageObj.setMessage(message.getString("message"));
           return messageObj;
           } catch (JMSException e) {
             throw JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(e);
           }
       }
    }
```

MessageProducerBean.java :

```
package com.sarf.jms;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MapMessage;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator;
import com.sarf.data.MessageObject;

public class MessageProducerBean {

     //JMS Template object
     private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
     private Destination destination;
     public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
         this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
     }
     public void setDestination(Destination destination) {
         this.destination = destination;
     }
     public void sendMessage(final MessageObject messageObj) {
      jmsTemplate.send(destination, new MessageCreator() {
      public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            MapMessage message = session.createMapMessage();
            message.setString("mailId", messageObj.getMailId());
            message.setString("message", messageObj.getMessage());
            return message;
           }
      }); //send method close here
     }//method ends here 
    }
```

Homecontroller :

```
package com.sarf.testactimq;

import java.text.DateFormat;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.sarf.data.MessageObject;
import com.sarf.jms.MessageProducerBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.sarf.jms.*;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );
         MessageProducerBean mp = new MessageProducerBean();
         mp.sendMessage(new MessageObject("1234", "Test Message"));
            /*
         MessageConsumerBean mc = new MessageConsumerBean();
                MessageObject messageObj = mc.receiveMessage();
                System.out.println("Message from " + 
                 messageObj.getMailId() + " received");
        */
        return "home";
    }

}
```

servlete_context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

             <beans:bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <beans:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="mailDestination"
        class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="mail.queue" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jmsTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <beans:property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="producer"
        class="com.sarf.jms.MessageProducerBean">
        <beans:property name="destination" ref="mailDestination" />
        <beans:property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </beans:bean>
     <beans:bean id="consumer"
        class="com.sarf.jms.MessageConsumerBean">
        <beans:property name="destination" ref="mailDestination" />
        <beans:property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sarf.testactimq" />



</beans:beans>
```

root_context.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
             <bean id="connectionFactory"
        class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailDestination"
        class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="mail.queue" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="producer"
        class="com.sarf.jms.MessageProducerBean">
        <property name="destination" ref="mailDestination" />
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean>
     <bean id="consumer"
        class="com.sarf.jms.MessageConsumerBean">
        <property name="destination" ref="mailDestination" />
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sarf</groupId>
    <artifactId>testactimq</artifactId>
    <name>testmessage</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
      <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
      <version>5.13.3</version>
   </dependency>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

the error in run time caused by call the methode sendMessage which define in MessageProducerBean  called in my controller , I run my activemq as image shown below :
[image]
Note :I am using spring suite tool with tc server and activemq version 5.13.3 
 so what wrong I am doing any help ?

Comment: Why are you trying to instantiate `MessageProducerBean` and `MessageConsumerBean` in the `HomeController` instead of autowiring them? Due to this the jmsTemplate and destination are null in both of them when trying to use from the controller. Also your bean definitions are duplicated in root_context.xml and servlet_context.xml files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `HomeController` you are creating the `MessageProducerBean` like so:

```
MessageProducerBean mp = new MessageProducerBean();
```

And then immediately using the `MessageProducerBean` to send a message:

```
mp.sendMessage(new MessageObject("1234", "Test Message"));
```

However, at this point `MessageProducerBean` is attempting to use the `jmsTemplate` variable which you haven't initialized so it's `null`.  Hence you receive a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.